# Editing root-owned files after "unshare -Ur"

Tags: linux, linux-namespaces

Say I am in the initial user namespace and there is an empty root-owned file in some directory:

```
tdiff@tp:~/temp/unshare$ sudo touch root.txt
tdiff@tp:~/temp/unshare$ ls
total 8.0K
drwxrwxr-x 2 tdiff tdiff 4.0K Oct 18 02:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 tdiff tdiff 4.0K Oct 18 02:37 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root     0 Oct 18 02:37 root.txt
```

Now I am switching to a new user namespace with `unshare -Ur`. In this namespace, *root.txt* is reported to be owned by *"nobody"* because original *root* uid(0) is not mapped to the new namespace:

```
tdiff@tp:~/temp/unshare$ unshare -Ur 
root@tp:~/temp/unshare# ls
total 8.0K
drwxrwxr-x 2 root   root    4.0K Oct 18 02:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root    4.0K Oct 18 02:37 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup    0 Oct 18 02:45 root.txt
```

Then I use `vim` to edit this file. Despite giving some warnings about changing readonly file, it allows me to overwrite the contents of the file:

```
root@tp:~/temp/unshare# vim root.txt && cat root.txt
added from unshare
```

Also, if I return to the initial user namespace, the file has now changed its owner to my unpriviledged uid(1000):

```
root@tp:~/temp/unshare# logout
tdiff@tp:~/temp/unshare$ ls
total 12K
drwxrwxr-x 2 tdiff tdiff 4.0K Oct 18 02:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 tdiff tdiff 4.0K Oct 18 02:37 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 tdiff tdiff   19 Oct 18 02:47 root.txt
```

How is it possible? Also, if I try to do the same with system root file (e.g. */etc/passwd*), I get access denied error as expected.

UPD:

```
tdiff@tp:~/temp/unshare$ uname -a
Linux tp 5.4.0-51-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 5 14:28:49 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you edit/save *root.txt* through `vim`, the file is renamed into *root.txt~* and renamed back into *root.txt* as *tdiff* user (as well as the *root* user counterpart in the child user namespace) has write access in the directory *~/temp/unshare*. The renaming operation changes the ownership on the resulting file to *root* in the child namespace which is *tdiff* in the father namespace.

For */etc/passwd*, the same is impossible as */etc* is not owned by *tdiff*: you don't have access write to rename the file during the edition.

Comment: Thanks, I see now it is unrelated to namespaces at all.